# Want to access controls in another class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to access control created in xaml to C# (code) in another class, rather than in typical MainWindow class. I have tried every thing, but I am not getting where I am doing mistake.

Assume I want to access textbox created in xaml

```
<TextBox  x:Name="textBox2" x:FieldModifier="public"  />
```

and I want to access it in class login

```
class login 
{
//some code 
}
```

I am getting error  : textbox2 doesnt exist in current context.

Comment: More code is needed.  How is your login class getting the instance of the `Window` object?  You'll need that if you want to access its members.

Comment: Well no - you've got to specify an *instance* of your window... although ideally you'd communicate through a ViewModel anyway, I suspect.

Comment: I didn't see anything from everything that you did.

Comment: I'm going to give the quick "You shouldn't be doing this" since it really is bad practice. What are you trying to accomplish? There probably is a better way.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET +1.  No well-coded WPF app I've ever seen has ever tried to access `Window` members like that.  Do some research on MVVM and try again :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I am trying to implement singleton pattern on my previously created software.

Comment: That doesn't tell us much... Still, you should either have an instance of "Window" to talk to, or design the app correctly and access the values via MVVM. Tons of people here will help with that, but we need a bit more information.